# How can I mklink to a file share so that a web can save uploaded files to it?

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, security, fileshare

How can I mklink to a file share so that a web can save uploaded files to it?

My web and file servers are both apart of a workgroup. I don’t care about security and do not want a domain solution.
Originally, I had AWeb with subfolder: Work folder and it’s subfolders with modified permissions for IIS_IUSRS and my AppPool Indentity set as NetworkService... and it works great.
Now, I want to replace the Files folder with a symbolic link to a file share.
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AWeb\Work\Files

From elevated prompt:
mklink /d “C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AWeb\Work\Files” “\\FileServer\Files”

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AWeb\Work\Files

This works under my account, but not for NetworkService account.  How can I get this to work?  I’ve tried some of the solutions in forums like elevating the prompt to administrator then to system using psexec.exe but still no go.
How can I log or check what’s really happening when I get the error that access is denied?
How can could I set the file share access for an account like NetworkService when I have no idea what the password is?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the best way is to setup iSCSI target and initialator. But would still like to try without.